# Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 update freezes on Windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: windows-8, freeze, windows-phone-7.1.1

I can't get WinPhone 7 SDK update v7.1.1 to install. It freezes my computer everytime I try to install, the mouse still work but after a while whole system locked up and I need to hold power button to turn it off. Looked at task manager and look like it freeze when configure the emulator. Tried several time, even reinstall Windows and still no luck. Anyone know a work around on this? I saw some others faced this problem but no solution.

Comment: Are you running it on the Windows 8 release preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it freezes (in particular, when the spinning icon freezes), try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> once. Two things can happen:

The first is that the machine will completely freeze within a minute or two, which will require a hard reboot.

The second is that the screen will flicker quickly, attempting to show the "Lock/Switch user/Sign out/Change password/Task manager" screen, and then will jump back to the setup screen.  You'll then see the progress icon start spinning again, but it will hesitate several more times.  It will either freeze the machine again (and if so, do a hard reboot and try again), or setup will eventually complete (which on my machine took no longer than 10 minutes).